# mysql select multi rows equal from row

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, operator-keyword

I have two tables:

```
TableA          TableB
ID_A            ID_B
P1              Text
P2
P3
P4
```

---

```
TableB
ID_B    Text
1       Bla
2       Blabla
3       Bla bla ecc
4       Bla Bla
5       Bla bla Bla
6       Bla bla bla bla
7       Bla bli
```

---

```
TableA
ID_A    P1  P2  P3  P4
1       5   6   6   6
```

---

```
SELECT ID_A,  P1, P2, P3, P4,
       ID_B, Text
FROM TableA, TableB
WHERE (TableA.P1 = TableB.IDB) OR
      (TableA.P2 = TableB.IDB) OR
      (TableA.P3 = TableB.IDB) OR
      (TableA.P4 = TableB.IDB);
```

I get:

```
ID_A    P1  P2  P3  P4 ID_B Text
1       5   6   6   6   5    Bla bla Bla
1       5   6   6   6   6    Bla bla bla bla
```

How can I get this?

```
ID_A    P1  P2  P3  P4 ID_B Text
1       5   6   6   6   5    Bla bla Bla
1       5   6   6   6   6    Bla bla bla bla
1       5   6   6   6   6    Bla bla bla bla
1       5   6   6   6   6    Bla bla bla bla
```

my query is more complex, I have summarized the problem

Comment: start from using explicit joins instead of implicit. Implicit have been deprecated long ago

Comment: I don't get it.  Maybe simplify your problem/data if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you have to build a table of rows from the `P*` columns of `tableA`. This can then be joined to `tableA` on `ID_A` and to `tableB` on the individual `P*` values:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM (SELECT ID_A, P1 AS P FROM TableA
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ID_A, P2 FROM TableA
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ID_A, P3 FROM TableA
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ID_A, P4 FROM TableA) p
JOIN TableA a ON a.ID_A = p.ID_A
JOIN TableB b ON b.ID_B = p.P
ORDER BY a.ID_A, b.ID_B
```

Output (for my expanded demo):

```
ID_A    P1  P2  P3  P4  ID_B    Text
1       5   6   6   6   5       Bla bla Bla
1       5   6   6   6   6       Bla bla bla bla
1       5   6   6   6   6       Bla bla bla bla
1       5   6   6   6   6       Bla bla bla bla
2       3   4   5   6   3       Bla bla ecc
2       3   4   5   6   4       Bla Bla
2       3   4   5   6   5       Bla bla Bla
2       3   4   5   6   6       Bla bla bla bla
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nRpqNiUmpRVJJ4gMP66Ywn/0)

Comment: For Nick, I'm sorry
there is a bug in your code.
Please can you help me?
In the rows they are not correctly correlated,
you can see in the example
the first row, text must be "G" no "F"

[Demo on dbfiddle update][1]


  [1]: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nRpqNiUmpRVJJ4gMP66Ywn/2

Comment: @carmelocony haven't been at my computer but I've answered your other question.